# too few arguments to function 'fgets' in C

Tags: c

Whenever I compile this I get that error, and I am not sure why. I am copying this straight out of a book. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[256];

    printf("Enter your name and press enter:\n");
    fgets(buffer);

    printf("Your name has %d characters and spaces!", strlen(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The book should throw  to trash box.

Answer (score 4):

Use `fgets()` because the `gets()` function is a common source of buffer overflow vulnerabilities and should never be used.

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

- *str* -- This is the pointer to an array of chars where the string read
  is stored.
- *n* -- This is the maximum number of characters to be read (including
  the final null-character). Usually, the length of the array passed as
  str is used.
- *stream* -- This is the pointer to a FILE object that identifies the
  stream where characters are read from.

Comment: Thanks. Upon checking several times, my book still has fgets(buffer). Is this an error? I just don't get it.

Comment: Yes. I think It's mistyped.

Comment: @WalterStraub Yes, this book has an error (and probably more than one)

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname Why `-1` in `strlen(buffer)-countSpaces-1`?

Comment: The function `fgets()` adds a newline at the end of the string read. @AlexD

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname: "... adds a newline at the end of the string" **it does not always do this**! This missing is a flag that indicates the buffer was too small, and a next `fgets` will read the remainder of the current line.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname It may lead to a problem e.g. if you redirect input from a file, which does not have a new-line.

Comment: mentioned things are surmountable only with conditions. There is no need to make a big thing of it.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname BTW, the current code has UB when input is redirected from an empty file. According to my tests, `null`-terminator is not written in that case. But even if a zero-length string would be created, `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]` would be UB.

Comment: Now okey @AlexD you can edit my post. I've just removed my code that was already extra. So, I've written it for an example. If you try to detonate it  , you can do it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

[`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) takes three parameters. Did they mean [`gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) perhaps?

Comment: No, it is fgets, and there is indeed one parameter. That is odd.

Comment: Ok, gets worked, thank-you. I guess that was what they meant.

Comment: Yes. According to the C standard: `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,
FILE * restrict stream);`

Comment: In between editions they may have picked up to "use `fgets` instead of `gets`" and took it a bit too literally.

Comment: @WalterStraub: don't use `gets`, it *will* introduce a point of failure in your program.  It was deprecated in the 1999 standard and has been removed from the latest (2011) standard.  That one library function has been responsible for all kinds of mayhem over the last 40 years.  It is unsafe and insecure *by design*, and should not be used in new code.

Comment: gets is not anymore in c11, we have to use fgets

Comment: @aurelien Another alternative is `gets_s`.

Answer (score 2):

The book's code `fgets(buffer);` does not match any C compiler using standard libraries.  Code corrected below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char buffer[256];
  printf("Enter your name and press enter:\n");
  // fgets(buffer);
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {

    // Remove potential \n
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

    // printf("Your name has %d ...
    printf("Your name has %zu characters and spaces!\n", strlen(buffer));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

1. `fgets()` takes 3 parameters: buffer, size, stream.

   > char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
2. Always check return value with I/O functions.
3. Remove potential `'\n'` as `printf(..."characters and spaces" ...)` reports as if `\n` was not there.
4. `strlen()` return type `size_t`.  To print, use specifier `"%zu"`.

Comment: As it is discussed in the comment thread for http://stackoverflow.com/a/30791263/3246555, `fgets` often, although not always, adds `\n`.

Comment: @AlexD detail: `fgets()` does not add a `'\n'` any differently from any other `char` it reads.  It reads a number of `char`, be it `'A'`, `'\n'`, or `'\0'` - any `char` value - and stores that in a buffer.  Reading a `'\n'` is 1 of 3 terminating conditions for a successful read (other 2: buffer full, EOF after data).  `fgets()` does _add_ a terminating `'\0'` to the buffer making it a C string.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I meant that from user's point of view, the output will look off-by-one, since `strlen(buffer)` will count new-line as a character in the name.

Comment: @AlexD Good catch [Off-by-one_error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error): code updated to deal with the pesky `'\n'` and match the context of the "characters and spaces"

Comment: What's special about `%zu`?  I got two warnings during compilation (`unknown conversion type` and `too many arguments for format`) and my output printed "zu" rather than the number of digits.  I replaced `%zu` with `%d` and the number was printed to output as expected.

Comment: @harperville If you are using a C99 (or later) compliant  compiler, `"%zu"` is _specified_ to work correctly with _all_ possible values returned from `strlen(buffer)`.  `"%d"` may work with some compliers and some values - it may not.  It depends really how portable you  want code.  If obliged to use an old or non-compliant compiler, `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) strlen(buffer));` is a good alternative.  What C compiler are you using?