# Why do I keep getting a 'fgets' function error in my C program and how do I fix it?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, gets

I am writing a program in C that requires us to use arrays and pointers. It reads in four characters and then prints them out in a rotated pattern.  For example, if the input characters are ABCD, the output will be (with no leading spaces):

```
           ABCD
           BCDA
           CDAB
           DABC
```

We also need to write a function RotateFourChars using pointers and a "temp" variable to
store c1 (the first character) in order to rotate the characters.

Here is the code I wrote for it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void RotateFourChars(char *p){
    printf("/n%s",p);
    char temp;
    int j;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            temp = *p;
            //pritnf("\nTemp :%c", temp);
                    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                            *(p + j) = *(p + (j + 1));
                    }
                    *(p + j) = temp;
                    *(p + (j + 1)) = '\0';
                    printf("\n%s",p);
    }
}
int  main(){
    char c[4];
    printf("\nEnter 4 charcters: ");
    fgets(c);
    printf("\nRotated Pattern: ");
    RotateFourChars(c);

}
```

This is the error I keep getting:

In function ‘main’:

lab7.c:22:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘fgets’
fgets(c);
^
In file included from lab7.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:622:14: note: declared here
extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
^

I'm not sure what arguments I'm missing. Can someone help ? (Sorry if this question is all over the place.)

Comment: Looks like a warning rather than error. Use something more safe (`fgets`) to get rid of it.

Comment: For updated error message see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791172/too-few-arguments-to-function-fgets-in-c.